# Why SSH breaks the control flow in Bash

Tags: bash, ssh, while-loop

I have following script scanning through a file, each line is hostname of a remote node.

```
echo -e "node1\nnode2\nnode3" > tempfile
while read aline; do
  echo "@$aline";  
done < tempfile
```

this produces `@node1` `@node2` and `@node3` correctly in three lines. But when I add `ssh` inside the loop, as follows

```
while read aline; do
  echo "@$aline"; 
  ssh $aline 'jps';  
done < tempfile
```

The loop will break after first invocation of `ssh` and prints only `@node1` (without `@node2` and `` `@node3 ``).

I am asking what happened behind the scene (it looks like undefined behaviour)? And how should one realise the same functionality without breaking the while loop.

Comment: Try `ssh -n $aline 'jps';`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SSH is doing something with stdin (which is redirected from `tempfile`) and messing up the `read`s. Try redirecting stdin.

```
ssh -n $aline 'jps'
```

From `man ssh`:

> **`-n`**  Redirects stdin from /dev/null (actually, prevents reading from stdin).

Comment: ...or `ssh -n $aline 'jps'`